# Google map takes over on click even when its inside the Card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code.

```
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = CutCornerShape(0),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(10.dp),
        onClick = { onCardClick.invoke() }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
        ) {
            GoogleMap(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                cameraPositionState = positionState
            ) {
            //...
            }
            //...
        }
    }
```

I want to have interaction Source in the Card but no matter what I've tried google map always takes over. I've tried changing the interaction source inside googleMap modifier and there is no disable for on click events either.

If I changed googleMap with Column the interaction worked without any issues.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue. How did you get around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Managed to work around it by overlaying a transparent Surface over it. Careful though, it has to be a Surface, otherwise it won't work. I didn't dig deep enough to understand why, but give this a try.

```
Box {
    GoogleMap()
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
        color = Color.Transparent
    ) { }
}
```